# What is JIRA rest api to logout an user and is the below the correct approach to login and logout an user using JIRA Rest api?

Tags: objective-c, api, ios7, jira, jira-rest-api

I am developing an iOS application that connects with jira instance and i login  using NSURLConnection like below -

```
NSString *authStr =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@:%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];

NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://hp.myDomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?"]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

and as i am using a BASIC authentication which is stateless and i wanted to know how can i logout the user now , i have tried the below code when a logout button is clicked . Can anyone please let me know if it is the right code and what is the right rest api for jira to logout an user?

```
   -(IBAction)logout:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL       URLWithString:@"http://www.myDoamin.co/logout.htm"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    //[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];
    [conn initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 }
```

Comment: You do not need to logout since as you stated: BASIC authentication is stateless.

Comment: oh ok thanks , but when i login using the rest api once it seems in the application the state is maintained as i was not using rest api to get data for other functions like create request , post a comment , so i was thinking state is maintained and asked this question.